# Using SUM & COUNTIFS against unique ID

Tags: excel, sum, countif

I have a dataset that exports all actions by a candidate appointment database, but as the candidate can be booked for more than one appointment all I want to check is the candidate has attended one appointment within the given month.

Currently I use the below formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(ActionsImport[Activity Type], "Appointment*", ActionsImport[Status/Outcome], "Attended", ActionsImport[Activity Date], ">="&AS2, ActionsImport[Activity Date], "<="&AZ2))
```

`ActionsImport[Activity Type]` - Is to look for all Appointments

`ActionsImport[Status/Outcome]` - Is if they have attended

`ActionsImport[Activity Date]` - Is the start and end date range

I also have `ActionsImport[Candidate ID]` that I can use as a unique identifier, but I'm not sure how I would go about creating the unique search. I have been looking into `SUMPRODUCT` and `FREQUENCY`, but without much luck.

Comment: Exactly one appointment, or at least one appointment?

Comment: at least one, not a specific